# How to disable minimise-to-dock upon double-tapping Ctrl or Command?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Whenever I double-tap the Control (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> ) or Command ( <kbd>⌘</kbd>) keys, the current window is minimised into the dock.  Annoying as it's pretty easy to trigger this completely undesired behaviour.

I'm fairly sure this only started happening within the last few minor OS updates; I don't believe I've installed any sort of new keyboard-shortcut-enabling software (I installed Quicksilver about two years ago, but that's all).

Anyway, I can't find anything in the Keyboard shortcuts system settings, nor could I find any good search results about this particular problem.

This is with Mac OS X 10.5.8 on an early 2007 MacBook.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have [Window Shades](http://maketecheasier.com/mac-manage-your-app-windows-more-efficiently-with-windowshade-x/2009/09/20) installed?  They mention a double tap to minimize feature.

Comment: Hmm.. apparently I installed WindowShade X eleven months ago; I found a pref pane saying it's enabled, but that its demo has expired.  I tried disabling it, but it made no difference.  None of the listed shortcuts worked, and this particular double-tap feature wasn't set up.  I'll check again after a reboot to make sure.

Comment: I couldn't find anything other apps like this installed. Disabling WSX and adding every app it had listed to its exclusions list seemed to fix it. Still no idea how to actually uninstall it. I really should move back to Linux some day ;)  Thanks

Comment: Glad to have been of help.  (And not wanting to start one of the unholy Mac vs. Windows discussion, but coming from Windows I've been amazed at the lack of a operating system supported standard way of uninstalling stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't happen to me, I would double check anything you do have installed.

FWIW I had terrible experiences with any window modifying app for Mac. Window Shades, Sticky Windows, the bunch. I couldn't remove entirely either.